# How to track pagination information for multi database connection?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have following setup

MySQL server instance1
MySQL server instance2

in both these table I have a single table records which are partitioned. I have to retrieve the data from each instance and show the data in JQGrid.

Here are the consideration to be made:
1) From each database instance only 1000 records needs to be got.
2) Merge these 1000 records and sort in ascending order by a default column.
3) Again from the merged records get only 1000 records to be shown in a Grid.
4) For the next 1000 records we should not show any of the earlier records which have been shown.

The major problem I am having is how to uniquely identify the last row shown from the fetched records.

I thought about doing it this way:
1) Get the rowid for each record from all the connection. But from two instances the rowid would be same then how would I identify which record is from which database?
2) Check for rowid and primary key combination. But if the client sets the primary key's auto-increment value as same on all the instance then we would not get a unique combination.

Am I missing something or is there any other way to do it?

I am using JDBC connection to connect the database.

**[SOLVED IT]**
Solved the problem by writing a small function which calculates and create a map for the number of records to be fetched from each connection for each iteration.

Sorry can't add the code here as it is clients IP.

Answer (score 0):

You usually uniquely identify a row with a POJO class where you override your hashCode() and equals() methods basing on your class fields. You can put your last row into a HashMap and check against it. 
A rownumber retrieved from the tables can be achieved by creating one using RANK() and PARTITION BY. Create a temporary or tmp_ table with your merging results then drop it.

hope this helps abit.

Answer (score 0):

if the two mysql instance can see each other, how about create a view, UNION the two query results. then in java world, you could do query/pagination on this view?